# pdfbox - performance tuning

Tags: java, spring, pdfbox

How to enhance the below code to take less time, the below code takes 384 ms without applying any business logic after load the PDF.

Any suggestions ?

```java
MultipartFile file= ...;
byte[] pdfByte = file.getBytes();
PDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfByte));
List<PDSignature> signatures = pdfDoc.getSignatureDictionaries();
pdfDoc.close();
```

Comment: You can use a simpler `PDDocument.load()` overload, e.g. `PDDocument.load(file)` if the type of `file` is `java.io.File`. This could potentially avoid an unnecessary `byte[]` copy. That said, I'd bet that will not change much, will it? First of all, how did you measure 384ms? Benchmarking in Java is notoriously hard, e.g. the JVM needs to warm up to get to max performance for perf-critical tasks. To know for sure, you'll need to use JMH, and/or profiler to see where the time is being taken.

Comment: Thanks @PetrJaneček for your reply. The file type is Multipart.   I did a rest service that accept multipart file as an input and measured the time by postman response

Comment: Oh, but then you definitely need to measure exactly where you're spending your time (by profiling, look into async-profiler or Java Flight Recorder avilable via Java Mission Control). Anyway, I offer a possible solution that seems to be much faster on my machine.

Comment: Unrelated: don't close the file before you're done.

Comment: Thanks @PetrJaneček, I need to get the bytes to get  byte[] signatureAsBytes = signature.getContents(pdfByte);
  byte[] signedContentAsBytes = signature.getSignedContent(pdfByte);

Comment: @PetrJaneček where is the offered solution ?

Comment: The more relevant for me is: Why do you want to improve the performance? And what is the threshold?

Answer (score 1):

From the comments it turns out that the real question is how to speed up getting the signature bytes. Use this code to prevent reading the file a second time:

```
COSString contents = (COSString) signature.getCOSObject().getDictionaryObject(COSName.CONTENTS);
byte [] signatureBytes = contents.getBytes();
```

In PDFBox 2.0.22 there will be a new method `PDSignature.getContents()` without parameters which doesn't read the PDF a second time.

Another thing to speed up is to load the PDF like this:

```
PDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(pdfByte);
```

because loading from an InputStream would create another buffered copy.